# Families of distributions with bounded variations

Tags: probability, distributions, probability-inequalities, exponential-family

For what family of probability distributions $f(x)$ do we have the following property? 
$$
\forall x, \quad \int f(u) - f(u+x) du \leq L\| x \|
$$
for some $L$. Can we say anything about the exponential families?

Update: $f(\cdot)$ is the pdf.

Comment: What is $f(.)$?

Comment: Is $L$ supposed to be constant for the entire family or can it vary with the density $f$? (In the latter case, your criterion means the CDF $F$ is [Lipschitz continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).)